# Formatting Number With Comma

Tags: python

I am trying to put comma's on a number without striping any numbers after the decimal point.

number

```
12018093.1000
```

results

```
12,018,093.10
```

I tried this code but it strips away the last 0 which I don't know why.

```
rps_amount_f = ("{:,}".format(float(rps_amount_f)))
```

Comment: is `12018093.1000` a string or float?

Comment: @It_is_Chris a float

Comment: This has nothing to do with `{:,}`. The string `'100.100'` becomes the float  `100.1` when `float(...)` is called

Comment: @DeepSpace understood that thanks. I needed to do it to add the commas but then the zero is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the zeros are stripped away in your example, although this may be a solution using an f-string:

```
rps_amount_f = 12018093.1

rps_amount_f_str = f"{rps_amount_f:,.10f}"
```

Here '10' before the f is the decimal precision you want to have in the string, i.e. 10 decimals in this case.

Comment: The zeros are not "stripped". Even just `print(1.100)` outputs `1.0`. Python removes unnecessary zeros

Answer (score 1):

You said that you only want one zero so really isn't the solution just to add a 0 to the end of the string? Anyway here's my solution:

```
if("." in str(rps_amount_f)):
    rps_amount_f = ("{:,}".format(float(rps_amount_f)) + "0")
else:
    rps_amount_f = ("{:,}".format(float(rps_amount_f)))
```

If you want two decimal places you just get rid of the if statement and round it.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("{:,.4f}".format(float(rps_amount_f))) # 12,018,093.1000
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: not *quite* what OP asks for, as this will **always** have 4 decimal places, even if the input has less or more

Comment: @DeepSpace I get you. But my telepathic receptors aren't so good lately. I would give OP a chance to clarify his intentions. On rare occasions  wonders happen and we get feedback from  a questioner.